# Office API, save mail item to disk

Tags: outlook, add-in, office365

Using the "new" office 365 api, is there any way to save a mail item to disk as an .msg file? I'm creating an outlook add-in using the "new" office 365 technology, and i need to save the item out of outlook to put the .msg version into sharepoint.

I've been researching for hours, but no luck.

related question: but the answer for using MailItem.SaveAs refers to the "COM" (old) technology, not the new office 365 api technology.
[How can I convert an Outlook MailItem object to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187160/how-can-i-convert-an-outlook-mailitem-object-to-a-byte)

microsoft documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createattachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EWS to [export to an .eml file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx), but .msg files are only native to Outlook so you'd have to use a third-party converter for that.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for pointing out this method. I think this will do the trick.

Comment: In testing the export: i received a ..."web method unavailable.." error.It appears "export" isn't an EWS method for mail add-ins - per a link in this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/ec6a3bb5-fa98-4f04-8b0e-1f7cadc40059/office-2013-outlook-app-the-requested-web-method-is-unavailable-to-this-caller-or-application?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment.  I'm going to try this for now: <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:MimeContent" />

Comment: GetItem should be supported though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160952.aspx#mod_off15_appscope_CallingWebServices_SupportedEWS

Comment: Yes, GetItem is supported, and i can use that to get the MIME content. Now i have to figure out how to convert the MIME content to a byte array.